PowerShell equivalent to DISM's /Cleanup-Image in Windows 10
What is the PowerShell equivalent to DISM's /Cleanup-Image in this command:
DISM /Image:%mounted_image% /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /Resetbase /ScratchDir:%scratch_dir%

Within Use DISM in Windows PowerShell, there is no corresponding PowerShell cmdlet, so is this Repair-WindowsImage command the equivalent to the above command?
Repair-WindowsImage -Path $mounted_image -RestoreHealth -ScratchDirectory $scratch_dir


@Gantendo ? The PowerShell Dism cmdlets are within the link Use DISM in Windows PowerShell, which links to Dism cmdlet Repair-WindowsImage (I go into more detail in the answer)


The parameters of Dism commands are an almost 1:1 to the parameters of PowerShell's Dism cmdlets, with the main difference being cmdlets use - instead of /, coupled with some additional paraemeters, such as -ScratchDirectory, being supported for Package Servicing. 
The man page for the equivalent Dism cmdlets is Use DISM in Windows PowerShell, which links to cmdlet Repair-WindowsImage:

Repair-WindowsImage <-Online | -Path> is the equivalent of:
Dism </Online | /Image:> /Cleanup-Image


Repair-WindowsImage cmdlet command:
Repair-WindowsImage -Path $mounted_image -RestoreHealth -ScratchDirectory $scratch_dir

is not the equivalent of /StartComponentCleanup:
# There is no /ScratchDirectory parameter:
  Dism /Image:$mounted_image /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /Resetbase

Instead, it's the equivalent of /RestoreHealth:
Dism /Image:$mounted_image /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth






Correct Repair-WindowsImage command: (-ScratchDirectory not required)
Repair-WindowsImage -Path $mounted_image -StartComponentCleanup -ResetBase -ScratchDirectory $scratch_dir


If running against an online Windows image [%SystemDrive% | $env:SystemDrive], -Online is used in lieu of -Path, however one or the other must be specified:

-Online: services packages of an online [booted to] Windows image e.g. Dism /Online
-Path: services packages of an offline [non-booted to] Windows image  e.g. Dism /Image:<path> 




I'm not sure about the other switches, but
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
works perfectly fine in powershell.

This is not an answer, it's a comment, and /RestoreHealth is not the same as /StartComponentCleanup
